# smartgwt problem with relationship between the two listgrids

Tags: smartgwt

I have two listgrid. My 1st listgrid is holding Record(List of Field) and my 2nd listGrid is holding record(field). And my issue is i have to assign multiple record(multiple rows) of 2nd list grid to the single record(Single row) of 1st grid on the action on Button.and 1st ListGridRecord is list of 2nd ListGridRecord. Hope i am able to forward my thought to you. Please reply me as soon as possible. Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify your question a little bit?

Comment: my 1st list grid is holding FieldRecords and my 2nd list grid is holding FieldRecord. FieldRecords is Collection of FieldRecord. and now i want to assign group of FieldRecord(from my 2nd ListGrid) to one FieldRecords(Which is my 1st ListGrid) with a action of Button.

Comment: when the user clicks some button.. You need to add/move more than one record(selected records) from 2nd Listgrid to 1st Listgrid as a single record.. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: yes @karthikeyan your understanding is right.